# Store Variable with an Enum Value

Tags: postgresql, database-design, enums

Im new in SQL(Still leanrning).
I'm trying to create a relational database for a venue to manage event.
I have an attribute which store which room has been reserved.
The data type is ENUM.
My problem is that I need my ENUM values(ex: Main room) to hold int values.
Each room has a capacity seat and capacity stand. I not supposed to insert it in my table every time someone reserved for a room.
But in the end i should be able to ask how many people can a room hold.
Is this possible? I did not see anything about holding variable on the intenet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *learning* database design, stay away from enums. They essentially break normalization - which might sometimes be a solution to a specific problem, but is not something you should use while still trying to understand the concepts. You should rather use a properly normalized model with a one-to-many relationship.

As you need to store additional information with the room type, an enum is out of the question in the first place - this is not what enums are for (and you can't do it).

A clean model would be something like this:

```
create table room_type
(
   type_id integer primary key,
   name varchar not null unique,
   max_capacity_seats integer not null, 
   max_capacity_standing integer not null
);

create table room
(
  room_id integer primary key, 
  room_type_id integer not null references room_type,
  description varchar, 
  ... other columns ...
);
```